# Impossible to set the default gateway address on boot-up

Tags: debian, network-interface, ethernet, ppp, beagleboneblack

I am using a BeagleBone embedded computer running Debian.

I have two network interfaces :

1) A connection to a cellular modem over USB which uses ppp and connects to the outside world. It receives a dynamic IP address from the ISP

2) An ethernet interface which is connected only to another local device. I have assigned a static IP address to this interface 192.168.1.40 by putting this command in rc.local `ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.40 netmask 255.255.255.0`

Only when the two interfaces are active, there is a problem to connect out through the modem. I realised that to solve this I have to set the default gateway to the address that the modem gets by running a script with my below commands.

```
#!/bin/sh
IPADD=$(/sbin/ifconfig ppp0 | grep 'inet' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $2}')
route add default gw $IPADD
```

This works great when I manually execute my script after login. I can then communicate out through the two interfaces.

However, I am not able whatsoever to get this script to execute on boot-up properly and assign the the default gateway address automatically this way.

I have tried everything, by running it from rc.local, putting the script in /etc/rc5.d or /etc/rc3.d, running it from /root/.bashrc or /user/.bashrc. Using crontab, trying to sleep 1 minute before running the script, running it in a loop. Nothing works.

It seems after I login, the default gateway gets overwritten somehow from having the ethernet interface.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this? I need this default gateway address to be assigned on boot-up automatically. I've been trying for days now.

If I don't have the ethernet cable plugged in , or I put the ethernet interface down, there are no problems at all. Only with the two interfaces active I have this problem. Thanks

Comment: How have you  configured your static address on the ethernet interface?  Please edit your question with relevant configuration files or snippets.

Comment: @user4556274 I've configured it in rc.local. I've edited the question

Comment: Do you also have NetworkManager running? Run `systemctl status NetworkManager` to find out. If you do your network configuration in `/etc/rc.local`, what's in `/etc/network/interfaces`, the "classic" default network configuration file for Debian? If it includes a default DHCP setting for the ethernet interface, the DHCP client might be the one wiping out your default gateway settings. If you don't want to use `/etc/network/interfaces`, make it empty or comment out all lines in it.

Comment: @telcoM I have nothing inside /etc/network/interfaces. This was causing problems for me at first, because the ppp0 interface was never showing up if i set the ethernet interface in there. I therefore decided to use rc.local instead to set up the ethernet IP address after the ppp0 interface, because ppp is set up using a systemd service. As far as I know there is no DHCP client for the ethernet interface that can be causing this.

Comment: If the `ppp` configuration includes the `defaultroute` keyword then it should set the default route automatically when the ppp link is established.

Comment: @wurtel It does have the defaultroute keyword . I forgot to mention this, It still doesn't solve it tho